# Knapsack Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms, approximation, np-complete, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to model a scenario where there are n items, each having weight and volume. We also have m number of knapsack, each having a weight and volume capacity, where these items need to go inside. A feature that I am looking for is that the value property of each item which depends on which knapsack it goes into. For instance, item 1 has value of v1 if goes into knapsack 1, and v2 if it goes to knapsack 2.

How can I model the problem as a knapsack and an optimization problem so to maximize the overall value? So far I came into a multiple knapsack problem, 2 dimensional. For for the value, I don't have any clue.

Given that the problem will probably be NP-HARD/NP-Complete, I would need some approximation algorithms. So basically I need to model the problem and approximate it.

Comment: What do you want to do with this problem? "Model" it? Solve it? Approximate it?

Comment: Model and approximate!

Comment: What do you mean by model?

Comment: Is this a studied variation of KP? How to formulate it in KP language?!